# Is it possible to have a a django middleware module contain its own template and static files?

Tags: django, middleware

I migrated my DUO 2FA to the middleware layer and it does the following:

```
If the request is not authenticated through DUO, render the template containing the DUO login form
```

My problem is, my middleware contains this code, but I'm pulling the template and static files from the templates folder for my frontend application and static files from my frontend application as well. Is it possible to contain both the depending template and static files within a middleware module?

Here's a simplified view of how the folder structure looks like

```
djangoproject
   myapp
      settings.py
      duo_middleware
          middlewareclass.py
   frontend
      views.py
      template
          index.html
          duo-login.html
      static
          someduodependency.js
```

I'm looking for a possibility on adding a templates folder within the duo_middleware and a static folder